# How to ignore “Missing Permissions” error and reply with a message? (Discord)

Tags: discord.js

If you’ve experienced with Discord.js a good bit, you would know:

`DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions`

I’ve dealt with this error before, and it’s easy to fix, but I don’t want this error to crash my bot when my bot becomes public and users try to do something that requires a permission the bot just can’t do.

How am I able to send a message saying “I don’t have Permissions to do this!” and so on? I also don’t want to add code in all of my commands. I want to make this universal. Something in my main file.

So Instead of the DiscordAPIError in console, the user would get a message or Direct Message (In certain occasions) saying this:

```
Sorry, I don’t have permissions to do this, please contact an Administrator for more information.
```

Comment: To do that, you would need to [catch the exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch), and send the message to the appropriate channel/user in the `catch` block.

Comment: I understand this, but where in the world do I catch the exception if i want to make this universal. So if the bot is unable to send the message, usually the code inside for example: ping.js, will catch the exception, and will direct message the user or the owner saying Permissions are needed. But this catch exception code will only be in ping.js, as I add more commands, I don’t want for every line of code to have an exception. So I want this to be universal instead, where I can just forget about this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch error and ignore it when you call `message.channel.send`

**Example:**
(1)

```js
try {
    message.channel.send("Foo bar");
} catch () {} /*Ignore error*/
```

(2)

```js
message.channel.send("Foo bar").catch(() => {/*Ignore error*/})
```

Comment: The first one won't work, as try/catch doesn't catch promise rejections. You have to await it

Answer (score 0):

Like Wolf suggested on the second example, if you want to send them message, just `.catch()` it.

```js
message.channel.send("Your super cool message here").catch(e => {
    message.author.send("Missing permissions to do this!");
    console.log(e);
}
```

The reason why you should rather send a message to the command sender/message author than send the message again saying no permission is because you already got an API error trying to send a message to that channel, so the second message won't do any difference.